# Updated Windows 10, now Bitnami Wamp Apache will not start

Tags: apache, windows-10, wamp, httpd.conf, bitnami

Updated Windows 10 today and now the apache server will not start in Bitnami WAMP.

This is the Windows error I'm getting `httpd.exe: Could not open configuration file C:/Program Files/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.1-0/apache2/conf/httpd.confN: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Also from Bitnami server events:

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 1
Stdout:

Stderr:
Unknown error starting apache"
```

It looks as if there is a "N" at the end of the file request that shouldn't be there. I don't know how to fix that, or what else could be the problem. Before I ran the system updates this morning everything was working properly.

Comment: Have you looked at the Windows Event Viewer for messages from Apache? They are usually very useful and informative

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Developer here,

I suggest you to check the contents of this `.bat` file

`<installdir>/apache2/scripts/serviceinstall.bat`

If it looks ok execute

`<installdir>/apache2/scripts/serviceinstall.bat remove
<installdir>/apache2/scripts/serviceinstall.bat install`

This will reinstall the service correctly.